# overflow:scrollで内包されている要素の中のツールチップの実装がしたい

Tags: javascript, html, css

サンプルコード

```
<div class="layer1" style="overflow:scroll;">
<ul>
    <li class="layer2" style="position:relative;">
        <button>btn</button>
        <p class="tooltip" style="display:none;position:absolute;"></p>
    </li>
    <li class="layer2" style="position:relative;">
        <button>btn</button>
        <p class="tooltip" style="display:none;position:absolute;"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

例えばこんな形で、スクロール範囲内の要素の中のそれぞれのリストに対して、
JavaScriptでbuttonのclickイベントをきっかけに
position:absoluteのブロックを表示させるUIを作りたいのですが
このままやると、当然ですがoverflow:scrollを指定しているdiv要素の中で見切れてしまうのです。

ツールチップUIがoverflow:scrollを指定しているdiv要素より上のレイヤーに表示されている見た目にするためには、どのような実装方法がありますでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layer1`内のものはどうにもできません。`z-index`したとしても結局は`layer1`内なので。
そもそもそれができてしまうと`overflow`指定の存在意義がないというか･･･

実装方法の一例を示します。`layer1`とは別の`div`要素に表示させます。
こんな感じです。

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('button').on('click', function(e){
        var str = $(this).parent().find('.tooltip').html();
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        $('#target').html(str).css({
            'display' : 'block',
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'top' : offset.top + 20,
            'left' : offset.left + 20
        }).fadeIn();
    }).on('mouseleave', function(e){
        $('#target').fadeOut();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="layer1" style="overflow:scroll; width:150px; height:200px;">
<ul style="line-height: 2.5em;">
    <li class="layer2">
        <button>ボタン1</button>
        <p class="tooltip" style="display:none;">ボタン1のツールチップ</p>
    </li>
    <li class="layer2">
        <button>ボタン2</button>
        <p class="tooltip" style="display:none;">ボタン2のツールチップ</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="target" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: 大変丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます！
こちらの実装方法を参考に、やってみたいとおもいます！助かりました！

Answer (score 0):

jquery-uiのtooltipとかを使えば簡単に出来ると思います。
手作りしたいのであれば追加する時にlayer1の子要素としてではなく、bodyに直接追加して位置を指定すればいいと思います、

Comment: 迅速なご回答、ありがとうございます！
やはり、jsでクリックされた位置でbodyに表示、というのが妥当ですよね。。
このソースコードのままのCSSのみの実装は難しいでしょうか…？

Comment: js側のソースがないので何とも言えませんが、layer1の中に入っていたらcssだけ弄っても無駄かと。